# Is my proof of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x} = 0$ correct?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x} = h$$ then $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h^2 =  \frac{\cos^2(x) - 2\cos(x) + 1}{x^2}$$ substituting $$\cos^2x = 1 - \sin^2x$$ gives $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}h^2 =  \frac{2 - 2 \cos(x) - \sin^2x}{x^2}$$Since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 $$ It squared must also equal $1$. So $$ h^2 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{2 - 2 \cos(x)}{x^2} - 1 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  2\left(\frac{1-\cos(x) }{x}\right) . \frac{1}{x} - 1 = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \frac{2h}{x} - 1$$

If $h$ was a nonzero limit then the numerator would converge and since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x} = \infty$ the fraction would diverge to infinity. But since the limit cannot be infinity then the limit must be $0$.

Comment: Did you forget to put $\lim_{x \to 0}$ in two of the expressions starting with $h^2 =$?

Comment: Deducing limit of $h$ from that $h^2$ is ok. The problem lies in last step where you are trying to argue about converge / diverge.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  Doesn't the limit equal two limits multiplied?

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming from the beginning that the limit exist, and you apply algebra of limits without knowing if it converges, so is not correct altough the answer is correct

Comment: Since it appears in the derivative of sin(x) musn't it have a limit? Otherwise sin(x) wouldn't have a derivative?

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the comments above that you're assuming it already exists. You should try to approach it by manipulating only the limit.
So, I liked your logic of using the Pythagorean identity.
Think about multiplying both the numerator and denominator by an expression that will give you $1-cos^2(\theta)$ or similar to it $cos^2(\theta)-1=-sin^2(\theta)$).